# Nextjs getStaticProps error when passing an object as prop instead of plain string

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I hope you're doing fine .

Playing around with the new internalization NextJS feature, I found out an error I was not expecting at all.

**If I pass a plain string as prop from the `getStaticProps` to the `Page Component` everything works fine in the `default locale`, but if I pass down an object instead of a plain string, it breaks.**

I leave both codes here.

**The following code is the one that works fine :**

- it passes down a string value
- works fine in both locales `/en` and `/es` even without it (it picks the default locale)

```
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { name: `victor`, locale: "es" } },
      { params: { name: `victor`, locale: "en" } },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { name } = params;

  return {
    props: {
      name,
    },
  };
}

/*
 * ✅ The following URLs work
 * - localhost:3000/victor
 * - localhost:3000/en/victor
 * - localhost:3000/es/victor
 *
 * TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'person' as it is undefined.
 */
export default function PageComponent({ name }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div>The name is: {name}</div>
      <div>Locale used /{router.locale}/</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**The following code is the one that DOESN'T WORK :**

- It passes down an object
- Works fine in '/en' and without explicit locale (default locale) but doesn't work with `/es`

```
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { name: `victor`, locale: "es" } },
      { params: { name: `victor`, locale: "en" } },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { name } = params;

  return {
    props: {
      person: {
        name,
      },
    },
  };
}

/*
 * ✅ The following URLs work
 * - localhost:3000/victor
 * - localhost:3000/en/victor
 *
 *  The following URLs DOESN'T work
 * - localhost:3000/es/victor
 *
 * TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'person' as it is undefined.
 */
export default function PageComponent(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { person } = props;
  const { name } = person;
  return (
    <>
      <div>The name is: {name}</div>
      <div>Locale used /{router.locale}/</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using `fallback: true`.

The page is rendered before the data is ready, you need to use `router.isFallback` flag to handle this situation inside your component:

```
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
```

Or you can use `fallback: 'blocking'` to make Next.js wait for the data before render the page.

[More info in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required)

Comment: but that's something I don´t understand... and If I get that person asynchronously and force it to be a sync prcocess with await, would it work? That was totally it, I tried it and it worked, I appreciate it , I was so frustrated! 